# How can the CPU time be lower than wall-clock time on GHC's RTS stats?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a program linked with `-rtsopts` and called with `+RTS -s` and on the timing I get this:

```
  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    4.047s  (  9.694s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.578s  (  0.514s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.004s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    4.625s  ( 10.209s elapsed)
```

This program was running for about 10 seconds.
It's linked with the threaded RTS but it uses `-N1` so I don't get why there would be a difference in the first place between wall-clock time and CPU time.

And I just found this in the GHC user guide:

> Next there is the CPU time and wall clock time elapsed broken down by
>   what the runtime system was doing at the time.

So, how does it make sense that the CPU time is lower than wall-clock time?

Note: my computer didn't do any hard work during the execution of my program, certainly not that much.. which is why I'm confused and worry my program is misbehaving.

Update: I think I may have found the culprit: does the RTS count the cpu time for IO? if it doesn't then that's probably the reason, there are tons of writes.

Comment: CPU time is the time assigned by the system to your application. Wall clock time is the real time as we use on earth (Einstein might have some things to say about that). So your application got less then 100% of the wall clock time available (only about 45%). The rest was spent on something else.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Something completely external to the program? I ask because my computer didn't do any hard work during the execution that would take that much resources, so something is a bit peculiar to me, and I'm a bit worried it's my program that's misbehaving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wall-clock time includes time spent waiting for the network, disk, user input, etc. whereas CPU time only includes time actively spent computing something on (exactly) one CPU. (When computing on multiple CPUs, the time spent on each is added together.)